# After dispatching a method of redux Action creators. The whole app is reloading continuously? Literally not getting what is happening?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I was storing my JWT token in local storage. Now when ever I close and open my app in new tab my store data is being lost. So to handle that I am checking if the user is logged in using JWT token and if he is then I am fetching user data again from the server and storing it to the redux store. While doing so My page is continuously reloading.

```
 componentDidMount() { //When main component mounts
        if (localStorage.getItem("token") && !this.props.user.LoggedIn) {
            this.props.alreadyLoggedin();
        }
    }
```

These are the function inside my ActionCreators.js

```
export const alreadyLoggedin = () => dispatch => {
    console.log("already loggedin");
    return fetch(baseUrl + "user/getuserdata", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
        },
        credentials: "same-origin"
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            } else {
                var error = new Error(
                    "Error " + response.status + ": " + response.statusText
                );
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        },
            error => {
                throw error;
            }
        ).then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            dispatch(
                loggedinUser(
                    response.email,
                    response.name,
                    response.id,
                    response.image,
                    response.orders,
                    response.accountType,
                    response.favourites,
                    response.preference,
                    response.phone
                )
            );
            window.location = "/userprofile";
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            alert("Wrong Credentials/ Kindly check email or password");
        });
};

export const loggedinUser = (email, username, id, image, userorders, accountType, preference, favourites, phone) => ({

    type: actionTypes.LOGIN_USER,
    payload: {
        email: email,
        username: username,
        id: id,
        profilepic: image,
        userorders: userorders,
        accountType: accountType,
        preference: preference,
        favourites: favourites,
        phone: phone
    }

});
```

And finally this my User store

```
import * as actionTypes from "./ActionTypes";
export const User = (
    state = {
        LoggedIn: false,
        UserData: {},
        errMess: null
    },
    action
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.LOGIN_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                LoggedIn: true,
                errMess: null,
                UserData: action.payload
            };
        case actionTypes.LOGOUT_USER:
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            return {
                ...state,
                LoggedIn: false,
                errMess: null,
                UserData: action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: is `componentDidMount() {` called in `/userprofile` route?

Comment: @EhsanNazeri No, It's not being called in /userprofile but it was being called in MainComponent where are the routes are being switched including /userprofile too.

Comment: I think before `UserData` is set  with `redux` in store , you call `window.location = "/userprofile";` and page is reloaded so this `this.props.user.LoggedIn` would always be `false`